# Spring mvc Requestmapping or getmapping doesnt work

Tags: spring-mvc

I have seen the code and changed application.properties but both @RequestMapping
and @GetMapping doesnt work. The code is as follows

```
package com.tp.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


/**
  * Created by ssaatya on 06/04/17.
*/

 @Controller
 public class IndexController {

   @GetMapping("/")
   public String index(){
       return "index";
   }
 }
```

The full code is at here https://github.com/ssaatya/TP

Answer (score 0):

Try to add @ResponseBody before type of return value.

```
package com.tp.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;


/**
  * Created by ssaatya on 06/04/17.
*/

 @Controller
 public class IndexController {

   @GetMapping("/")
   public @ResponseBody String index(){
       return "index";
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the RestController, so you don't need the ResponseBody annotation.

```
 @RestController
 public class IndexController {
   @GetMapping("/")
   public String index(){
     return "index";
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using @Controller, use @RestController and set the controller endpoint and then the other endpoints.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/indexs")
public class IndexController {

 @GetMapping("/test")
 public String index(){
   return "index";
 }
}
```

OBS:In this case, to access the index () method, the endpoint will be localhost:port/indexs/test